# How to use a value from the if statement?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to use a value that is created inside an "if statement" and print it outside of it but to create a pop up it does not recognize it and I do not know why. Can someone help me please??

```
@Override
public void onClick (View v){
    int sum = uno + dos + tres + cuatro;
    double pru = sum*8;
    if(sum == 11){
        double tot = pru - (pru*.01);
        String tot1 = String.valueOf(tot);
    }
    if(sum == 12){
        double tot = pru - (pru*.02);
        String tot1 = String.valueOf(tot);
    }
    if(sum == 13){
        double tot = pru - (pru*.03);
        String tot1 = String.valueOf(tot);
    }
    if(sum == 14){
        double tot = pru - (pru*.04);
        String tot1 = String.valueOf(tot);
    }
    if(sum == 15){
        double tot = pru - (pru*.05);
        String tot1 = String.valueOf(tot);
    }
    if(sum == 16){
        double tot = pru - (pru*.06);
        String tot1 = String.valueOf(tot);
    }
    if(sum == 17){
        double tot = pru - (pru*.07);
        String tot1 = String.valueOf(tot);
    }
    if(sum == 18){
        double tot = pru - (pru*.08);
        String tot1 = String.valueOf(tot);
    }
    if(sum == 19){
        double tot = pru - (pru*.09);
        String tot1 = String.valueOf(tot);
    }
    if(sum >= 20){
        double tot;
        tot = pru - (pru*.1);
        String tot1 = String.valueOf(tot);
    }

print tot1;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29

The short answer is that you can't do what you're trying to do. A variable born in an if block vanishes when you exit the if block. That is known as a variable "going out of scope".

To solve your issue, declare the variable outside your if block. I won't reproduce your entire code, but it will look something like this:

```
int sum = uno + dos + tres + cuatro;
double pru = sum*8;
String tot1 = "";
if(sum == 11){
    double tot = pru - (pru*.01);
    tot1 = String.valueOf(tot);
}
print tot1;
```

Just do that for all of your if statements.

Comment: Also note that for this particular use case, he can do it all based in math.

Answer (score 2):

Your entire code can be reduced to a few lines by recognizing that the `pru` variable's mulitplier has this relation to the `sum`:

```
multiplier = (sum - 10) / 100, for 11 <= sum <= 20
```

Then all you really need is a single `if` statement to handle things.

```
@Override
public void onClick (View v){
    int sum = uno + dos + tres + cuatro;
    double pru = sum*8;
    String tot1 = "";
    if (sum >= 11 && sum <= 20) {
        double multiplier = (sum - 10) / 100.0;
        double tot = pru - (pru * multiplier);
        tot1 = String.valueOf(tot);
    }

    System.out.println(tot1);
}
```

And if you *did* really need all those `if` statements, a nicer way to handle it would be to use a `switch` statement.  You can read about that [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to define tot1 outside all the if statements as follows:

```
String tot1;
if (sum == 10)
    ...
    ...
print tot1;
```

Now you might get a warning that tot1 might not have been initialized - you will have to take care of it (either assign a default value to it, or check if tot1 is null and deal with it)

Answer (score 1):

A tip for you: If you're repeating the same code over and over again, you're doing something wrong. You should always have this sentence in your head when programming.

Note: In this example you should use a SINGLE if statement. But as an example to show you, in the future, there's something called loop!

Your code could be something like this with loops:

```
    @Override
public void onClick (View v){
    int sum = uno + dos + tres + cuatro;
       double pru = sum*8;
        double tot;
        String tot1;
    if(sum >= 20)
    {
        double tot;
        tot = pru - (pru*.1);
        String tot1 = String.valueOf(tot);
    }
    else
    {
        for (double x = 11, i = .01; x < 20; x++, i+=0.1)
        {
            if (sum == x)
            {
                tot  = pru - (pru*i);
                tot1  = String.valueOf(tot);
            }
        }
    }


print tot1;

}
```